# Get id of the overlapping divs on a fixed div while scrolling

Tags: jquery

I have a fixed div and when I scroll some divs overlap the fixed div .so my question is I need to get the id of the overlapping div? I'm pretty new to jQuery.
Here is my code

```js
function collision($fixed, $moving) {
  var x1 = $fixed.offset().left;
  var y1 = $fixed.offset().top;
  var h1 = $fixed.outerHeight(true);
  var w1 = $fixed.outerWidth(true);
  var b1 = y1 + h1;
  var r1 = x1 + w1;
  var x2 = $moving.offset().left;
  var y2 = $moving.offset().top;
  var h2 = $moving.outerHeight(true);
  var w2 = $moving.outerWidth(true);
  var b2 = y2 + h2;
  var r2 = x2 + w2;

  if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
  return true;
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
      var all = $(".moving");
      for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
         if (collision($(".fixed"), all.eq(i))) {
     console.log($('.moving').attr('id'));/* Help  Needed here */
           } else {
             $('.fixed').css('color', 'black');
           }
         }
      });
```

```css
.fixed {
  color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
}

.moving {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixed">
  Fixed Element
</div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="moving" id='1'>
</div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="moving" id='2'>
</div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="moving" id='3'>
</div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

I'm only getting the id of the first overlapped div.

Comment: Is there any way you can edit your code snippet to `console.log` when you get a collision?

Comment: Edited the code to give a console.log output.you can have a look. The outputs I need to be getting in console.log when the first div overlaps by is 1 and 2 when the second div overlaps and 3 on the third div.

Comment: That did the trick @WOUNDEDStevenJones.Thank you, much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.moving')` returns a list of elements, and calling `.attr('id')` on that list only returns the `id` attribute *of the first item*.

Instead, you want to use `all.eq(i).attr('id')` to get the ID of the `i`th element because you're checking the collision inside the loop.

```js
function collision($fixed, $moving) {
  var x1 = $fixed.offset().left;
  var y1 = $fixed.offset().top;
  var h1 = $fixed.outerHeight(true);
  var w1 = $fixed.outerWidth(true);
  var b1 = y1 + h1;
  var r1 = x1 + w1;
  var x2 = $moving.offset().left;
  var y2 = $moving.offset().top;
  var h2 = $moving.outerHeight(true);
  var w2 = $moving.outerWidth(true);
  var b2 = y2 + h2;
  var r2 = x2 + w2;

  if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
  return true;
}

$(window).scroll(function() {
      var all = $(".moving");
      for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
         if (collision($(".fixed"), all.eq(i))) {
             console.log(all.eq(i).attr('id'));
           } else {
             $('.fixed').css('color', 'black');
           }
         }
      });
```

```css
.fixed {
  color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
}

.moving {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fixed">
  Fixed Element
</div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="moving" id='1'>
</div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="moving" id='2'>
</div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="moving" id='3'>
</div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```